# Does a device with no physical SIM slot have an IMEI?

Tags: imei

In telephony, an [IMSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity) identifies a SIM card and, hence, a user. An [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) identifies the device itself.

If an Android device does not physically have a SIM card slot, does it still have an IMEI? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId%28%29) is not clear on this.

---

[Update] Since I don't have access to such a device, would someoen be so kind as to test it programatically? Just add call to `GetDeviceId()` into the code of an existing app. Thanks a 1,000,.000

Comment: Well, nope I don't think that a telephone that doesn't have a SIM card will posses IMEI number as there's no need of IMEI number over it. IMEI itself stands for International Mobile Equipment Identity, and I guess its only made for SIM card slots one SIM card slot over a device one IMEI number, 2 SIM card slots over the device 2 IMEI number. So, as far as I know I don't think it will posses IMEI number rather than such devices are identified by using something different maybe mac address or ....

Comment: From the Wikipedia itself, "*The IMEI number is used by a GSM network [...]*", so if it doesn't have telephony, it won't have IMEI. Also, anecdotally, Nexus 7 (tablet) doesn't have IMEI.

Comment: @Peter, sorry to correct you, but you are 100% dead wrong. A device with 2 SIM slots can have 0, 1 or 2 IMSIs, depending on how many SIM cards are inserted. It will always have exactly one IMEI, independent of SIM cards.

Comment: As for your edit, I'd say [this post on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802644/will-telephonymanger-getdeviceid-return-device-id-for-tablets-like-galaxy-tab) is related.

Comment: I think the existence of a GSM radio is more important than the existence of a SIM slot.

Comment: I think you are correct (+1). The IMEI is really only necessary obtain a (P-)TMSI

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but don't emulator instances constitute as "devices" that don't have a physical SIM card slot but still has an IMEI?  Granted, the value seems able to be spoofed as whatever the user wants or randomly generated (by all appearances, I've yet to find any functional need to touch those settings), but they appear to be recognized by Google Play services as actual devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question, because I finally found a definitive answer. [This S.O post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802644/will-telephonymanger-getdeviceid-return-device-id-for-tablets-like-galaxy-tab/8145184#8145184) says

> "Google's CTS require that getPhoneType of TelephonyManager needs to
>   be none and getDeviceId of TelephonyManager needs to be null for
>   non-phone devices."

Answer (score 8):

I had a look at a tablet which does not have a SIM card slot and it does not have an IMEI number in the About Tablet settings menu.

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145184/1504365) should help you find an ID for a device with a SIM card slot and for those devices without.

Answer (score 2):

My Azpen A727 tablet doesn't have a SIM card slot but it does have an IMEI number.

I see this number under Devices on my Google Dashboard.

[image]

Comment: How certain are you of this, as it seems to contradict what everyone else says? Could you post a screen shot, or even just tell us how many digits it has? Thanks

Comment: I have been researching about Azpen/iNet A727, and until now, I couldn't find any info if this device has SIM slot or not. But the text "No carrier" confused me, since it seems to support telephony, but no SIM card. This is just my opinion: the manufacturer probably didn't implement the code correctly, or there is a way to use telephony without SIM. As contradicting with other answer, this is a valid answer with proof.

Comment: It's probably the world's most low-end tablet, so anything is possible.  But you definitely cannot use it as a phone at least as it is configured from the manufacturer.'